# What is the minimum possible k-rank of a quasi-split reductive group over a field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

It is not possible for a quasi-split reductive group $G$ over a field $k$ to be anisotropic (unless it is solvable, hence its connected component is a torus). Indeed, there exists a proper $k$-parabolic $P \subseteq G$ if and only if there exists a non-central $k$-split torus, by the dynamic criterion.

Does a more careful analysis of this process (or any other argument) give a lower bound on the split-rank of a quasi-split reductive group? For example in type A, one can manually find a lower bound of $n/2$, where $n$ is the rank of the group (with a small modification for the center, maybe). Does this generalize to an arbitrary reductive group in a natural way?

Comment: The rank of a quasi-split semisimple group is the number of orbits of the Galois group on the set of simple roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I add details to Friedrich's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456611/what-is-the-minimum-possible-k-rank-of-a-quasi-split-reductive-group-over-a-fiel#comment1182627_456611):

The question easily reduces to the case of a semisimple group. Let $G$ be a quasi-split semisimple group over a field $k$. Let $B\subset G$ be a Borel subgroup defined over $k$,
and let $T\subset B$ be a maximal torus. Consider the Dynkin diagram $D=D( G^s,T^s,B^s)$ of our triple over a separable closure  $k^s$ of $k$. The absolute  Galois group $\Gamma=\Gal(k^s/k)$ naturally acts on $D$. Then the $k$-rank of $G$ is the number of orbits of $\Gamma$ in $D$.

EDIT-1: we provide details.
Namely, let $S=S(G^s,T^s,B^s)$ denote the set of simple roots. We may assume that $S$ is the set of vertices of $D$. Let $O\subseteq D$ be an orbit of $\Gamma$ in $S$. For each simple root  $\alpha\in O\subseteq S$,
let
$$\alpha^\vee\colon {\Bbb G}_{{\rm m},k^s}\to T^s$$
denote the corresponding coroot. Consider the cocharacter
$$\nu_O=\sum_{\alpha\in O}\alpha^\vee\colon {\Bbb G}_{{\rm m},k^s}\to T^s,\quad\ z\mapsto \prod_{\alpha\in O}\alpha^\vee(z)\ \,\text{for}\ z\in (k^s)^\times.$$

Then the image $\im \nu_O$ is a one-dimensional split subtorus of $T$. We may and shall assume that our semisimple group $G$ is simply connected; then the (direct) product
$$\prod_{O\subseteq S} \im \nu_O\subseteq T$$
is a maximal split subtorus of $T$ and a maximal split torus in $G$.
Its dimension is the number of orbits $O$ of $\Gamma$ in $S$.

EDIT-2 ([suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456611/what-is-the-minimum-possible-k-rank-of-a-quasi-split-reductive-group-over-a-fiel#comment1182801_456617) by @YCor). I consider a question of OP that I state as follows: Is it true that the $k$-rank of a quasi-split semisimple $k$-group is greater or equal to half of its absolute rank?

I add details to David's comment. Let us assume that $G$ is a *non-split* quasi-split *absolutely simple* $k$-group. Let $\Gamma_{\rm eff}$ denote the image of $\Gamma$ in $\Aut D$. Since $G$ is non-split, $\Gamma_{\rm eff}$ is non-trivial. Since $G$ is absolutely simple, $D$ is connected. Thus $D$ is a connected Dynkin diagram admitting non-trivial automorphisms. One can easily see that in the case ${\sf A}_n$ we have $\lceil n/2\rceil$ orbits, in the case ${\sf D}_n$ for $n\ge 5$ we have $n-1$ orbits, in the case ${\sf E}_6$ we have 4 orbits, and in the case ${\sf D}_4$ we have 2 or 3 orbits. Thus the answer is "Yes" for absolutely simple groups: indeed, the $k$-rank of $G$ is greater or equal to half of its absolute rank.

Now we do not assume that $G$ is absolutely simple. We can take $G=R_{K/k}\SL_{2,K}$ where $K/k$ is a finite separable extension of degree $n$, and $R_{K/k}$ denotes Weil's restriction of scalars. Then the absolute rank of $G$ is $n$, whereas the $k$-rank of $G$ is 1. Thus the answer is "No".

Comment: Does this answer the question whether the $k$-rank is $\ge$ rank$/2$?

Comment: @YCor In the simple case, yes. I don't know all the vocab in this question, so I can't check the correctness of the argument, but in the end it came down to counting orbits of a diagram automorphism group acting on a Dynkin diagram. The only connected Dynkin diagram with $>2$ automorphisms is $D_4$, and even in that case, there are $2$ orbits.

Comment: I'm not sure about the semisimple case, though. The Dynkin diagram of $\text{SL}_2^n$ is $n$ disjoint copies of the $A_1$ diagram, and you could have a group that permutes them transitively. I don't know if this can occur.

Comment: @YCor: I think that yes, it does answer this question in the negative.  We can take $G=R_{K/k}{\rm SL}_{2,K}$, where $K/k$ is a finite separable extension of degree $n$. Then the absolute rank of $G$ is $n$, whereas the $k$-rank of $G$ is 1.

Comment: @YCor: On the other hand, when $G$ is absolutely simple, we obtain the positive answer, see the first comment of David.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi OK that's a clear-cut conclusion, you might edit to add it.

Comment: Possible typo: I think all the $2n$'s when you discuss type $D$ should just be $n$. (Or, rather, what you wrote is true, but it is also true for $D_{\text{odd}}$.) Good answer!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Corrected! Thank you!